# Drop Down list from table to save value in foreign key

Tags: html, sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I have two tables:  Employer(ID(PK), Name) & student(ID, Name, Employer_ID(FK))

I have used dropdown list to show list of Names of employer `@Html.DropDownList("Employer_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

but from this i would like to save the value of the employer rather than using the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Your List.

```cs
ViewBag.ItemID = new SelectList(yourItemList, "ItemID", "ItemName"); 

@Html.DropDownList("ItemID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Good luck.

Comment: I got the list sir.... But, When i try to save the data into database table i would like to save it by emploee_ID is this posssible ?

Comment: You are post your model in view. If you are do this, possible.